# Algoritmo profundidade - grafo - DEFS

Tags: c++

Quando aplica o algoritmo lista de adjacentes na busca em profundidade - DFS com um conjunto de vértices e seus adjacentes, o algoritmo apresenta um resultado, se alterar a ordem dos adjacentes de pelo menos um vértice, o resultado é outro. Ou seja, os vértices visitados no algoritmo tem a sua ordem de visitação alterados de acordo com a ordem dos vértices adjacentes de um determinado vértice.

Pergunto se os vértices visitados deveriam ser os mesmos, independente da ordem de input dos vértices adjacentes de um determinado vértice para gerar a lista de adjacência?